# ls -al throws garble. unable to see ownerships, all replaced with interrogation ? symbols

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

Error using command `ls -al /xx` throws garble. i've tried to copy, modify ownership, permissions but no changes. it happens for root and users as well. I'm running systemd in sysv mode (`apt install systemd-sysv`). as init replacement. I can't define where that ??? comes from.

```
$ ls -al /xbin    
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? ..
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? ADMIN
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? apt-commands.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? build-kernel.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? cairo-dock.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? chrome.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? dirwatch.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? export_notebook.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? find_duplicates.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? findsortdate.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? functions.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? get-chromium.sh
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? get-kernel.sh
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? .git
-????????? ? ? ? ? ? github-create.sh
```

Could it be something related to extended attributes?

Comment: Is your filesystem corrupt? Does the output of the `dmesg` command show any interesting errors?

Comment: nope. dmesg displays a charm. i had a couple reboots (hibernation failed), no major mess, the journal apparantly took charge of the missing files, but i assume it's other direction. i've not e2chked thoug but i assume ls chowns using IPC. but didn't test that far yet.

Comment: the thing is i had apparmor running, after selinux. but didn't like it as it migrated to a meltdown safe kernels laltely. i assume apparmor messed with some folder permissions out of the basic root structure and then after removal those extended attributes are left unreadable. could it be?

Comment: chattr: bad version - /xbin
chattr: bad project - /xbin

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /xbin` and `getfattr -m '' -d /xbin` and `getfacl /xbin`?

Comment: Is the directory `/xbin` a remote network mount?

Answer (score 3):

`ls` with `-l`/`-n`... shows those `?` when it can list the contents of a directory but can't retrieve the metadata (with the `lstat()` or (with `-L`) `stat` system call, or variants such as `statx()`) of the files within.

A common case is when you have *read* permission (`r`) but not *search* permission (`x`) to the directory. In those cases, the `stat*()` system calls fail with `EACCESS` (*Permission Denied*).

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/{1,2}
$ chmod u=r,go= dir
$ ls -la dir
ls: cannot access 'dir/1': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'dir/..': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'dir/2': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'dir/.': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ./
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ../
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 1
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 2
```

Other cases  can come from filesystem corruption, when a directory contains entry that refer to inodes that are not there.

You can see it with `ls -lL` for broken symlinks:

```
$ ln -s /broken .
$ ln -s broken2 broken2
$ ls -lL
ls: cannot access 'broken2': Too many levels of symbolic links
ls: cannot access 'broken': No such file or directory
total 0
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? broken
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? broken2
```